# Exposing commands for MVVM user control inside GridView in WinRT

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Store application, following the MVVM pattern.
I have a Parent View (with matching Parent ViewModel) that contains a GridView control.
The ItemTemplate for that GridView control contains a Child View.
That child view contains a couple of buttons.

How do I wire it up such that when a user clicks a button on one of the ChildView controls, a method is called on the Parent ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I went about solving this problem.

1. Add an ICommand backed Dependency Property on the Child View code behind.

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildButtonCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ChildButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ChildView),new PropertyMetadata(null, OnChildButtonCommandChanged));

   public ICommand ChildButtonCommand
   {
       get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ChildButtonCommandProperty); }
       set { SetValue(ChildButtonCommandProperty, value); }
   }

   private static void OnChildButtonCommandChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       var self = (ChildView)sender;
       self.ChildButtonCommand.Command = (ICommand)e.NewValue;
   }
   ```
2. In the Parent ViewModel, add a public getter property of type ICommand, implemented with a RelayCommand that you can find here: https://relaycommandrt.codeplex.com/
3. In the Xaml of the Parent View, bind the ChildButtonCommand in the Child View:

   ```
   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <views:ChildView ChildButtonCommand="{Binding ElementName=ParentView, Path=DataContext.PropertyOnParentViewModel}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

> Examine the binding syntax closely. Since we're in a DataTemplate for the GridView Item, our DataContext is *not* the Parent View Model.(It's the child item objects). If we want to bind the button command to the Parent View Model, we need a reference to something in our parent view. In this case, I named the view "ParentView". Using the Binding ElementName syntax, I could bind to the DataContext of the ParentView and more specifically a property on the ParentViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods for doing this.

- first one that you can use is - bind your button to a command that is defined- in your parent viewmodel where you can do your work.
- second one is - you can use mvvm messenger class. in which you have to send message from your button click eventhandler to your viewmodel. when you received this message add some eventhandler to it and perform your work there.

Comment: Thanks for your help.With the first method you suggest, are you implying that the child view has a dependency on the parent view model?